# Syntax error when trying to find the length of a list using 'len' function

Tags: python, syntax, jython

Hi there I'm trying to find the length of a list for use in a method to find the average of all the numbers in said list but when I try to run the code

```
len(numList)
```

It gives me a syntax error and i don't know why. Everything I've read on the internet says that this function should work, but it doesn't. Here's the full method.

```
def mean(numList):
  i = 0
  total = 0     
  while len(numList) > i
     total = total + numList[i]
     i = i + 1
  print total
  return total
```

Comment: post the error report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the trailing colon needed in `if` statements!

Just change the line

```
while len(numList) > i
```

to

```
while len(numList) > i:
```

see the difference?  Just a trailing colon -- but it **is** a crucial bit of Python syntax!

Incidentally, I'd **vastly** simplify the code to

```
def mean(numList):
    return sum(numList)
```

to have exactly the same results as your code -- which seem wrong if by `mean` you mean `average`, but that could be fixed e.g as

```
def mean(numList):
    return sum(numList)/float(len(numList)) if numList else 0
```

as you appear to take the non-existent "mean" of an empty list as 0.  But, that's way beyond your trivial syntax error and probably worth a separate Q should any problem remain!-)

Comment: I changed my function to yours but i not sure how to have my main program print it. The point of the function is to pass back the average of the list to the main program so that it can be printed. That's why i had the average as a variable because i knew how to print that when it is passed back to my program. How do i print this when it is returned?

Comment: @Beid, you call `total=mean(numList)` followed by `print(total)`.

Comment: first of all thank you for your help I don't think i said it earlier :) . I've implemented your code but the actual calculation gives me this error message  "An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer."

Comment: @Beid, I don't recall seeing that error message in my 20 years of Python -- what version are you using?!  Please edit your Q to show the entire, properly formatted traceback, as well as the exact code you're using.

Comment: Sorry I found the problem it was in a different section of my code

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is semantically wrong. Perhaps:

return sum(numList)/len(numList)